# Changing action on clicking the close window button

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like for the 'x' button on the title bar to close the whole application, not the current form. How do I do that?

Comment: You do realize that this isn't how Windows applications are supposed to work, and it will be bad for your users. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wire up an event handler for the `FormClosed` event on the form and call `Application.Exit()`. For example:

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@rsbarro is right however I want to be more specific.

```
private void Form_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // if close button clicked, not the computer is being shutdown or anyother reason
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```